# When to use tensorflow datasets api versus pandas or numpy

Tags: csv, tensorflow, preprocessor, tensorflow-datasets

There are a number of guides I've seen on using LSTMs for time series in tensorflow, but I am still unsure about the current best practices in terms of reading and processing data - in particular, when one is supposed to use the `tf.data.Dataset` API.

In my situation I have a file `data.csv` with my `features`, and would like to do the following two tasks:

1. Compute targets - the target at time `t` is the percent change of 
   some column at some horizon, i.e.,

   ```
   labels[i] = features[i + h, -1] / features[i, -1] - 1
   ```

   I would like `h` to be a parameter here, so I can experiment with different horizons.
2. Get rolling windows - for training purposes, I need to roll my features into windows of length `window`:

   ```
   train_features[i] = features[i: i + window]
   ```

I am perfectly comfortable constructing these objects using `pandas` or `numpy`, so I'm not asking how to achieve this in general - my question is specifically what such a pipeline ought to look like in `tensorflow`.

Edit: I guess that I'd also like to know whether the 2 tasks I listed are suited for the dataset api, or if i'm better off using other libraries to deal with them?

Comment: Whenever possible, use the `tf.data.Datasets` API, as Tensorflow is better able to optimize read/write instead of it limiting training time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, note that you can use dataset API *with* pandas or numpy arrays as described in the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets):

> If all of your input data fit in memory, the simplest way to create a
>   `Dataset` from them is to convert them to `tf.Tensor` objects and use
>   `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`

A more interesting question is whether you should organize data pipeline with session `feed_dict` or via `Dataset` methods. As already stated in the comments, Dataset API is more efficient, because the data flows directly to the device, bypassing the client. From ["Performance Guide"](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#input_pipeline_optimization):

> While feeding data using a `feed_dict` offers a high level of
>   flexibility, in most instances using `feed_dict` does not scale
>   optimally. However, in instances where only a single GPU is being used
>   the difference can be negligible. Using the Dataset API is still
>   strongly recommended. Try to avoid the following:
>
> ```
> # feed_dict often results in suboptimal performance when using large inputs  
> sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
> ```

But, as they say themselves, the difference *may* be negligible and the GPU can still be fully utilized with ordinary `feed_dict` input. When the training speed is not critical, there's no difference, use any pipeline you feel comfortable with. When the speed is important and you have a large training set, the Dataset API seems a better choice, especially you plan distributed computation.

The Dataset API works nicely with text data, such as CSV files, checkout [this section of the dataset tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_text_data).