# Extract data from tensorflow dataset (e.g. to numpy)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm loading images via

```
data = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  './data', 
  labels='inferred', 
  label_mode='binary', 
  validation_split=0.2, 
  subset="training", 
  image_size=(img_height, img_width), 
  batch_size=sz_batch, 
  crop_to_aspect_ratio=True
)
```

I want to use the obtained data in non-tensorflow routines too. Therefore, I want to extract the data e.g. to numpy arrays. How can I achieve this? I can't use `tfds`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest unbatching your dataset and using `tf.data.Dataset.map`:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(180, 180),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  shuffle=False)

train_ds = train_ds.unbatch()
images = np.asarray(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)))
labels = np.asarray(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))
```

Or as suggested in the comments, you could also try just working with the batches and concatenating them afterwards:

```py
images = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)))
labels = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))
```

Or set `shuffle=True` and use `tf.TensorArray`:

```py
images = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
labels = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)

for x, y in train_ds.unbatch():
  images = images.write(images.size(), x)
  labels = labels.write(labels.size(), y)

images = tf.stack(images.stack(), axis=0)
labels = tf.stack(labels.stack(), axis=0)
```

Comment: I think iterating over batches and concatenating them in the end would be a faster approach.

Comment: Yes, definitely also an option!

Comment: If I'd disable shuffling, the answer below would already work. I want to avoid this because I'd have to shuffle the data afterwards.

Comment: @Frightera Iterating over batches does not always work to produce numpy arrays, as shown in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75352458/typeerror-expected-sequence-or-array-like-got-class-keras-engine-keras-tenso

Answer (score 0):

Because `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` returns a `Dataset` object, use [`tf.data.Dataset.as_numpy_iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#as_numpy_iterator). For example:

```py
for elem in data.as_numpy_iterator():
  print(elem)
```

In the end, its probably a better idea to use `tf.data.Dataset` because its more efficient. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48249019/17764230).

Comment: Hence, I have to iterate through all batches and I furthermore have to stack the numpy Tensors together myself - sounds quite cumbersome? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: @Steradiant -- You could always use `np.array(data.as_numpy_iterator())` to get your numpy array; Its not as efficient as using generators though. It really depends on what you're using it for; There is probably a better way using plain `tf.data.Dataset`.

Comment: `np.array(data.as_numpy_iterator())` did not really work. I need the x- and y-data (X_train and Y_train) as numpy tensors and arrays to use the data in algorithms outside tensorflow (e.g. sklearn).

Comment: @Steradiant -- Ah, I see. Your `X` will be `np.concatenate([x for x, y in data], axis=0)` and your `y` will be `np.concatenate([y for x, y in data], axis=0)`. You might want to consider removing `validation_split=0.2`, using `test_train_split` from scikit-learn instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. I rather prefer the way, that the `image_dataset_from_directory` already does the splitting because then I have the same split for sklearn and (if I want to implement it) the tensorflow NN.

Comment: @Steradiant -- No problem!

Comment: I encountered another problem. It seems, that the extracted data is not consistent anymore. Hence, the extracted labels don't fit to the images after exctraction to numpy array.