# How to return result from tf.data.Dataset.map as a single tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In tensorflow, when I use [`tf.data.Dataset.map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) to process data stored in a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), it will return a [`MapDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/MapDataset), for example

```
dataset.map(my_function)
```

might yield `<MapDataset shapes: (20, 2), types: tf.float32>`. I can iterate over this with a Python `for` loop:

```
for element in dataset.map(my_function):
    ...
```

What if I want to return the whole result as one tensor instead? My current solution is

```
res = dataset.map(my_function)
return tf.convert_to_tensor(list(res.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

which feels strange due to the explicit conversion to a numpy iterator and `list`. Is this the recommended way or what would be a better solution?

Comment: So you do not want to first convert to a numpy array? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535683/extract-data-from-tensorflow-dataset-e-g-to-numpy

Comment: Not if that's not needed, which I think it is not as I would like to return a `tf.Tensor`. If there is no overhead or problem with graph mode etc., maybe I'm overthinking this :)

Comment: Another alternative would be `tf.convert_to_tensor(list(res.map(lambda x: x)))` but it does not change much.

Comment: But then I am applying `map` two times (once with the target function and once with identity), isn't that redundant?

Comment: Then apply it once ;) --> `tf.convert_to_tensor(list(res))`

Comment: Ah, so you're just proposing to leave out the conversion to numpy, i.e. `tf.convert_to_tensor(list(res))`? (Not at my computer right now, cannot test.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73553553/