# dataset.map does not return / runs indefinitely in graph mode?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

The following code creates a tensorflow [`Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) with 3 elements and runs a trivial function on its elements using `map`. Importantly, the results are then converted to a Python `list`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(range(3)))
res_map = dataset.map(
    lambda x: x*2
)

# @tf.function # hangs in graph mode
def outer():
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(list(res_map))
res = outer()
print(res)
```

runs fine in eager mode and returns

```
tf.Tensor([0 2 4], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

as expected.

However, when I uncomment the decorator to run `outer`  in graph mode, the line `res = outer()` does not return (it runs for at least 10 minutes on my machine).

Is there a fundamental problem with my code or is this a (possibly known) bug / shortcoming of tensorflow? In the first case, what should I do differently? I am using tensorflow 2.2.0.